# how to fix the error `Company found no Lua executable` in Emacs

Tags: emacs, lua

My Emacs (24.5) on Ubuntu16.04 complains that

```
Company backend 'company-lua' could not be initialized:
Company found no Lua executable
```

I have installed and `lua-mode` `company-lua` via MELPA. The `lua` executable in my environment is `/usr/bin/lua5.3`, and there is no shortcut called `lua`,
and I cannot create shortcuts for environmental reasons.

Is there a way to let `company-lua` know the correct name or pathname for the Lua executable?

From [its website](https://github.com/ptrv/company-lua), company-lua does not seem to have a variable for setting Lua executable names as lua-mode has.

From [company-lua.el](https://github.com/ptrv/company-lua/blob/master/company-lua.el), I saw the following mentions of version, which seem to be wrong in 5.3. Is this something I should modify to fix the problem?

```
(defcustom company-lua-interpreter 'lua52
  "Lua interpreter."
  :group 'company-lua
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Lua 5.1" lua51)
                 (const :tag "Lua 5.2" lua52)
                 (const :tag "Lua 5.2" lua53)
                 (const :tag "LÖVE" love))
:safe #'symbolp)
```

Comment: Probably [this line](https://github.com/ptrv/company-lua/blob/master/company-lua.el#L39) sets the name of Lua executable.  Try to change it to `lua5.3`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks! That seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @EgorSkriptunoff, the problem is solved when modifying `company-lua-executable` variable to the right version of Lua, e.g. by adding the following the Emacs init file:

```
(custom-set-variables '(company-lua-executable (executable-find "lua5.3") ) )
```